# Reduction of algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Trying to see if a reduction exists for this <strike>equation</strike> expression, especially for y:

$((x - y) * z) - (a - y)$

Additive inverse

$((x - y) * z) + (-1)(a -y)$

$((x - y) * z) + (-a) - (-y)$

Communitive property, move "y" closer to where its being used to see if I can reduce further

$((x - y) * z) + (-a) + y$

$((x - y) * z) + y + (-a)$

$((x - y) * z) + y - a$

Distributive property for z

$(z*x - z*y) + y - a$

Parenthesis can be dropped

$z*x - z*y + y - a$

I'm not sure what other reductions can be made from here...

Comment: I think that works - if your aim is to simplify the expression as much as possible, then you'd write your end result as zx - zy + y - a, but using the * notation works too.

Comment: What you have is an "expression" instead of "equation". What you did is "expand" the expression. The end result is good.

Comment: @Somos thank you for the corrections, I have updated to reflect. I was trying to expand the expression in order to find any further simplifications that anyone else here might be able to identify. "y" seemed suspect given other "human" error factors from other related expressions.